# Javascript BBCode Parser recognizes only first list element

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, bbcode

I have a really simple Javascript BBCode Parser for client-side live preview (don't want to use Ajax for that). The problem ist, this parser only recognizes the first list element:

```
function bbcode_parser(str) {
search = new Array(
      /\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/,  
      /\[i\](.*?)\[\/i\]/,
      /\[img\](.*?)\[\/img\]/,
      /\[url\="?(.*?)"?\](.*?)\[\/url\]/,
      /\[quote](.*?)\[\/quote\]/,
      /\[list\=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/list\]/i,
      /\[list\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/list\]/i,
      /\[\*\]\s?(.*?)\n/);

replace = new Array(
      "<strong>$1</strong>",
      "<em>$1</em>",
      "<img src=\"$1\" alt=\"An image\">",
      "<a href=\"$1\">$2</a>",
      "<blockquote>$1</blockquote>",
      "<ol>$2</ol>",
      "<ul>$1</ul>",
      "<li>$1</li>");

for (i = 0; i < search.length; i++) {
    str = str.replace(search[i], replace[i]);
}

return str;}
```

[list]
[*] adfasdfdf
[*] asdfadsf
[*] asdfadss
[/list]

only the first element is converted to a HTML List element, the rest stays as BBCode:

adfasdfdf

[*] asdfadsf
[*] asdfadss

I tried playing around with "\s", "\S" and "\n" but I'm mostly used to PHP Regex and totally new to Javascript Regex. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For multiple matches you will need to use a regular expression with the `g` modifier:

```
  /\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/g,  
  /\[i\](.*?)\[\/i\]/g,
  /\[img\](.*?)\[\/img\]/g,
  /\[url\="?(.*?)"?\](.*?)\[\/url\]/g,
  /\[quote](.*?)\[\/quote\]/g,
  /\[list\=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/list\]/gi,
  /\[list\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/list\]/gi,
  /\[\*\]\s?(.*?)\n/g);
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding the g and m switches `/<regex>/gm` switches to your regex patterns.